# pgfplot: 3D version of a plane and its the gradient vector

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

Checking pgfplot for the addplot3-command was easy! I've found this very nice possibility to plot a plane:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[
    surf,
    mesh,
]
{x+y+1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

But to emphasize the meaning of the gradient vector I would like to add a vector (1,1,0). Furthermore I need labels for my coordinate system. And how can I add points, e.g. "the origin", to indicate that the functions returns 1 for x=y=0? Thanks for advice.

Here is a specification of the underlying problem: adding a circle or vector refers to the invisible 2d-coordinate system but not to the one plotted.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[
    surf,
        mesh,
]
{x+y+1};
\end{axis}
\draw[->] (1,1,0) -- (2,2,0);
\draw (0,0,1) circle (10pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$}]
\addplot3[
    surf, mesh
        ]
{x+y+1};
\draw[->, ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- (1,1,0);
\fill[red] (0,0,0) circle (2pt);
\draw[->] (1,1,0) -- (2,2,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Of course I just mixed up the environment of the addplot3 with the axis environment and possible other subsequent elements. Everythings fine now.

Comment: Just like with any other axis, you can use the regular TikZ drawing commands to add lines, nodes, etc. to the plot, with the usual 3D coordinate, e.g. `\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,1,0)`

Comment: Let me specify my problem. The coordinate system drawn is different from what my code works with.

Comment: You need put the `\draw` commands *inside* the `axis` environment, and you need to set `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` or use `(axis cs:0,0,0)` instead of `(0,0,0)`.

Comment: @Mac I agree with Jake (and I should have been more explicit). You can also use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` in the preamble (and I would recommend to use 1.13 which is the most recent version, unless you have a compelling reason to use an older version)

Comment: Sorry, where was my mind. I mixed up the environments, everythings fine now :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.